# Model aggregating in viewer - coordinate issue

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am dynamically aggregating models in the Viewer (coming from multiple BIM files). Basically, I initialize the viewer, and then LoadDocument and LoadModel for each model that user chooses to view, dynamically.

These are mostly NVC files (what I used for testing), which are sharing the coordinate system. Models getting dynamically loaded and getting 'stitched' correctly.

However, coordinate system is getting screwed up when the second model gets loaded - not always but in some cases (in v6.3 - haven't checked previous versions). When this happens, I can notice the followings:

1. When I click 'home' icon in the viewer, it doesn't show the full aggregated model but only shows the first loaded model in the center and rest go outside screen.
2. When I click an element to select, it selects something else (with an offset), and some cases selects nothing (meaning, clicked coordinates has been interpreted  incorrectly).

I have tried multiple combinations and this problem seems to happen when first loaded model is not occupying full size of the aggregated model (say, one floor of the building).

I figured out a solution though. After loading the models (every time when user choose some), if I 'hide' all models and 'show' them again, it fixes the problems with click and AGGREGATED_SELECTION event.

This is not a nice user experience because I want to be able to load the models in the background while user is moving around the previously aggregated model-set. If I hide/show after loading the new one, it will be annoying to user.

Is there a way to 'reset' the coordinate system of the viewer (to the same effect what happens when hide/show the models)?

I would appreciate some help to get around this issue.

Thanks
Bandu

Comment: Try disable the offsets like this: ``var loadOptions = {
        globalOffset: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            z: 0
        } // to align the models
    };`` and let us know how you go

Comment: Hi Bryan, it is not an alignment issue. They are perfectly aligned. Yes. I  am setting the globalOffset.

Thanks

Comment: Further tests reveled that my previous workaround is not reliable either (hiding/showing). It only works sometimes.

Comment: take a look at these hidden APIs for multi-model, that might give you a clue.  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/highlighting-clashes-multi-model

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks. I tried your 'reset view' code but it doesn't solve the issue. When I hide all models except one, selection works (it selects what I click). But when there are more than one model, it selects something different from the element I clicked. I tried with both 'sharedPropertyDb' and without - I don't think it makes a difference here.

Comment: @michaelbeale, Your code sample (clashes-multi-model) works I think because you are loading the larger model first, then the smaller on within same boundary. I replaced your URNs with my URNs and it shows the same problem I reported. I will email the code to you via forge-support@ address (I don't have your email). I can't share it because it contains customer's models.

Comment: Could you try loading the first URL of a large empty border square of plane ?   This may help solve the AaBb culling that's happening and causing flickering.

Comment: @michaelbeale Yes, if the first model loaded is a large one, it solves the problem but it is not suitable for my product. My user should be able to choose a section of the building and then enable other parts on demand. 

I also found another solution. If we restore a state previously saved that covers the entire area before fragments are loaded, that works too. It still doesn't solve the problem completely but I am going to use it as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so there is a massive offset, causing a precision issue.  Which is why you are seeing lots of 'jittering' of the camera.

To fix this... we need to correct the massive offset, by returning all the geometry closer to origin manually.  (or fixing the original navisworks file).

First, let's roughly figure out the offset value...

Hold down ALT-key and click anywhere on an object.  This sets a green dot, the pivot point.  Then use **viewer.navigation.getPivotPoint()** to get the x,y,z value.  (details: https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/issues/2).

You should see an xyz value like this...
Z.Vector3 {x: 1296285.515098644, y: 14995636.431742325, z: 364.26238179027337}

Now, adjust set the global offset using this value, to correctly move all the models closer to 0,0,0. like this...

line 70:

```
var modelOptions = {
    sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath(),
    globalOffset: {x:1296285.515098644, y: 14995636.431742325, z:0}
};
viewer.loadModel(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess);
```

`

This reverses the effect of this big offset.  The result is the geometry stops flickering and the camera movement stops 'jittering' due to precision issues.

Let me know if that works for you.
Michael

ps. you can pull the 'exact' global-offset out of the small side-file AECModelData.json, see blog: [forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-revit-levels-and-2d-minimap-your-3d](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-revit-levels-and-2d-minimap-your-3d)

Comment: Thanks Michael. That solved the problem. So, if I grab the offset from the first model and use it for other models (instead of using 0,0,0), this won't happen. I will restructure my code accordingly.

Comment: Incidentally, you can retrieve the globalOffset value before loading the viewer, using a neat trick...
Download the small AECModelData.json file, and pull the globalOffset out of there.
It works for Navis and IFC files.
See here for details:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api