# Why viewer showing broken geometry if the model is loaded partially?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

As our forge viewer app sometimes needs to load large model, we are trying partial loading as  mentioned here-

[Minimizing Viewer workloads](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only)

Now we are facing a strange problem. When we load a big element(single dbid) and try to rotate or zoom to the item, viewer displaying the item in a very strange way. It's like some parts of the item is cut down. Like this-
[image]

But the item should look like this -

[image]

It's not a problem for some other items of the same model. Could you please tell me what's going on here?

Comment: This is indeed very strange, can you share the model with us for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some heavy quantization artifacts...

This Looks like a 'large offset issue' bug.

Try shifting the model's global offset to the origin, like this article explains:
[Model aggregating in viewer - coordinate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764754/model-aggregating-in-viewer-coordinate-issue)

Comment: Yes, the large global offset was the issue. Now it is fixed. Thank you very much @michael. I have one other query to you. When I am trying to load the model partially using the ids I need to provide only the leaf node id. Is it possible to pass only a parent id and viewer will load all the leaves those are viewable? I tried but viewer shows empty model. I am wondering if there is any settings to make it works! You can answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980335/is-it-possible-to-load-a-huge-model-partially-using-only-the-parent-dbid