# Is it possible to load a huge model partially using only the parent dbid?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We know every node(parent or child) in the model browser tree has a unique id(dbId). When I am trying to load the model partially using the ids I need to provide only the leaf node id. Is it possible to pass only a parent id and viewer will load all the leaves? I tried but viewer shows empty model. I am wondering if there is any settings to make it works! Like, I will give the id of the green node only and viewer will load all the leaves those are in blue area(after finding all the leaves recursively).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the blog https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only.

In general, I don't see a way to use parent dbid only, you need to specify the leaf dbids as suggested, I am also discussing with our engineering team to see if any other way to do that, will update here if any.

Edited on 21 June, 2021: Confirmed with engineering team, parent dbid is not supported for now, wish to have this in future, and you can refer the blog https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer for the function to get all the leaf nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zhong. I had followed that blog to load the model partially. But got empty model error if I give only the parent node dbId. It says, there is no viewables. Please mention some way(s) if there is any after contacting with other guys.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zhong. The model I am talking about is huge. Some second level node contain millions of leaves. And we want these leaves dbIds beforehand. So we tried to store the parent - leaf dbId map in database. Our model gets changed and uploaded to bucket frequently that causes calculating those millions dbIds and store those again. That's why it would be very good if we can load the paren using only parent dbId. Anyway, will work on this if the feature is available.